# The Seprator line is fill parent..i want to fit to the golden border...How can i do?

Tags: android, custom-lists

[image]

In this image the golden seprator line is not fit to the screen..i want this line to be fit to the screen...i used the fill_parent..but this gives me this kind of layout...

This is my custom xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main"
     >




<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/seprater_line" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is the image you refer in your question

Comment: make your listview's width as fill_parent and give no margins for it from left and right.

Comment: @Shalini what he meant as screen shot as image.

Comment: actually there is an padding in your list view. if you post your view for golden line I will give you the solution.

Comment: @YogeshSomani i used fill_parent and not given any margins...

Comment: @Padma Kumar now only he update image

Comment: ok then , check for any paddings in the list view or your view for the divider line.

Answer (score 1):

The divider of a `ListView` is as wide as the `ListView` itself. Looking at your screenshot, you have set some margins or padding to your `ListView` which results in setting margin/padding for the divider too. Remove these attributes and your dividers will run over the whole width of the screen. By defining custom xml files for the rows themself, you can add your custom padding/margin there if you need it.